# Equivalent of data:text/html,foo but starting with http://

Tags: http

Is there a way to hardcode HTML data directly into a link starting by http:// ?

Like using a special local ip on a weird port that would echo the URL or something ?

The idea here is to store a HTML page inside a qr code that could be read offline. (Obviously that would be a small html page, but enough for a short leaflet)

Normally we can store data in a uri using data:text/html, but most qr core readers don't recognise anything that doesn't start with http://

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot.

The HTTP URI scheme describes only the location of a resource, it cannot be used to describe the resource itself.